# ggplot2: points to represent individual observations and bars to represent mean and sd

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, errorbar

I would like to build a plot like the following:

[image]

in which individual observations are represented as points, the mean for each group is represented as a line segment and two other segments denote mean+/-sd. I was able to generate the plot above with the code below, which uses `geom_crossbar` to draw the segments. However, this feels more like a hack. I'm new to `ggplot2` and I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve what I want.

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size=12, base_family="Helvetica"))

dat = data.frame(y=rnorm(10), treat=rep(c("A", "B"), each=5))
summData = dat %>% group_by(treat) %>% summarize(mean_y=mean(y), sd_y=sd(y))
summData$lower = summData$mean_y-summData$sd_y
summData$upper = summData$mean_y+summData$sd_y

mBarWidth = 0.5; sdBarWidth = 0.3
mBarSize = 2; sdBarSize = 0.8
barColor = adjustcolor("grey10", alpha.f=0.4)

p = ggplot()
p = p + geom_point(data=dat, aes(x=treat, y=y), color="skyblue")
p = p + geom_crossbar(data=summData, aes(x=treat, y=lower, ymin=lower, ymax=lower), width=sdBarWidth, color=barColor, fatten=1, size=sdBarSize)
p = p + geom_crossbar(data=summData, aes(x=treat, y=mean_y, ymin=mean_y, ymax=mean_y), width=mBarWidth, color=barColor, fatten=1, size=mBarSize)
p = p + geom_crossbar(data=summData, aes(x=treat, y=upper, ymin=upper, ymax=upper), width=sdBarWidth, color=barColor, fatten=1, size=sdBarSize)
p = p + xlab("Treatment") + ylab("Response")
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want vertical errorbar lines, you can use `stat_summary` to calculate the summary statistics, but use a point `geom` with a Unicode em dash character as the plot marker.

For example, in the code below, we use one call to `stat_summary` to calculate the mean and plot it as a blue line segment (by using a large em dash as the point marker), and a second call to `stat_summary` to calculate the locations of the +/- 1sd markers and plot them as red line segment (once again by using a large em dash). `"\U2014"`is the Unicode code for an em dash.

```
set.seed(1)
dat = data.frame(y=rnorm(10), treat=rep(c("A", "B"), each=5))

ggplot(dat, aes(treat, y)) + 
  geom_point(color="skyblue") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape="\U2014", size=9, colour="blue") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=function(d) {mean(d) + sd(d)*c(-1,1)}, geom="point", shape="\U2014", 
               size=7, colour="red")
```

[image]

You can actually get away with one call to `stat_summary`, but it requires a bit more work to specify the point marker sizes and colors:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(treat, y)) + 
  geom_point(color="skyblue") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=function(d) {mean(d) + sd(d)*c(-1,0,1)}, geom="point", shape="\U2014", 
               size=rep(c(7,9,7),2), colour=rep(c("red","blue","red"), 2))
```

Comment: Cool. Never thought of that.

Comment: thanks, I'm upvoting this because it does the job, but like the geom_crossbar solution it feels a bit like a hack, for example I don't see a way to independently control the width of the segment from its length using the `size` parameter, and occasionally one may need to do that. I have the feeling that the "right" solution would be to build a new custom geom that does exactly what I want, but I don't know `ggplot2` well enough to do that.

Comment: This is very nice. Would anyone know of a shape value that would mimic a dashed link like ----- ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in geom_errorbar in ggplot2

```
p = p + geom_errorbar(data=summData, aes(x=treat, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width=sdBarWidth, color=barColor)
```

I plot the mean as an open circle below as an example

```
p = p + geom_point(data=summData, aes(x=treat, y=mean_y), colour=barColor, size=3, shape=21, stroke=1, fill="white")
```

Comment: thanks, but I specifically would like a segment to denote the mean instead of a point, and also I would like that the upper and lower bars that denote mean+/-sd are not connected by a vertical line.